# Why is web browsing slow when I use a router, while torrents are fine?

Tags: browser, router, home-networking, timeout

I don't know if this is happening to anyone else. I am fairly sure my router may be dying. When I connect my computer to the cable modem directly, I get great internet service. Large downloads like videos and torrents are working great. Web browsing is fast. However, once I put my computer behind a router, web browsing becomes horrible at best. It takes about 4 or 5 tries to go a site (even google someimtes!!) and the browser will say that the site DOESN'T exist, when I know it does. Open up a terminal type: `ping google.com` gives me nothing. Ping SOMETIMES will display the IP Address of the google server it finds but can take about 90 secs or more to get 4 responses to the pings, but stats after I `^C` says that min/max/avg is like 20-50ms (should be normal?) Torrents and other stuff  seem to be unaffected though, it's just web browsing.

My router is linksys, and they seem to be really decent so I'm wondering if my router really IS dying and I need to get a new one, or if there is some other problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: What torrent client are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your router is going bad.
Try a hard reset **<sup>(1)</sup>** of the router, if that does not work borrow a router from someone else and check if you still have problems.

If you don't have any problems get a new router, if you do, something else besides the router is causing problems.

**(1)** Usually there is a small hole somewhere on the router to stick a paper-clip in.

Comment: A hard reset of one of out routers did the trick. The router I am referring to I believe might be going bad but after reseting it as well, it seemed to be better but not the best. I =1'ed everyone because they are all good answers but this did the trick. Actually, using a new router did the trick but hey... I need to finish this question.

Answer (score 1):

Check what DNS server is configured on the router. If it is set to get it from DHCP, change it to google DNS servers then, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Comment: I would have thought that the modem and the router would have the same dns if he used DHCP? But it's a good thing to check.

Comment: Some DNS servers works fine with Windows but poorly at best with Linux. Don't know why but I have experienced this myself

Answer (score 1):

Your router might be overheating. Try to vacuum it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Torrent downloading software created simultaneous connections which overload the router.

You can adjust the total number of connections on your torrent software to say 200 or lower and try. It will slow down the torrent downloads as the software won't be able to connect to as many peers but it will let you browse properly.